# Using functions leaves a white page

Tags: php, random, upload

So, I am using this:

```
if ($_POST) {
//some code here, doesn't matter I think
$newname = rand(1,99999). ".". end(explode(".",$_FILES["file"]["name"]));
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $newname);
}
```

But I am trying to do a function that looks like this:

```
function generateName($name) {
        $generatedname = rand(1,99999). ".". end(explode(".",$name));
        if (file_exists('upload/'.$generedname)) {
            return generateName($name);
        } else {
            return $generatedname;
        }
    }

if ($_POST) {
//again, code that doesn't really matter
$newname = generateName($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $newname);
}
```

But the problem is, whenever I try to load the page with that function, it just loads a white page.

Comment: Sounds like you need to turn error reporting on

Comment: sounds like you have an error and your server is configured not to show errors. Check your server logs

Comment: You have a typo that probably causes a never-ending loop: `$generedname` should be `$generatedname`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
if (file_exists('upload/'.$generedname)) {
```

It should be:

```
if (file_exists('upload/'.$generatedname)) {
```